# NSFetchedResultsController with item in multiple sections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a managed object to represent a spot on a map.  These points have zero-many types.  I want to also show a sectioned table view.  I had this working with an NSFetchedResultsController when type was a single value on the MapPOI object.  But now that the types are in a different objects with a relationship between "MapPOI" called "types", how do I write the query (can I?)

Original:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MapPOI"];

    if(searchString.length)
    {
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
    }
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES ],[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES ],nil ];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                                                managedObjectContext:self.campus.managedObjectContext
                                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:@"type"
                                                                                                       cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
       NSLog(@"Error performing institution fetch with search string %@: %@, %@", searchString, error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    return aFetchedResultsController;
}
```

i tried something like

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                                            managedObjectContext:self.campus.managedObjectContext
                                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:@"types.name"
                                                                                                       cacheName:nil];
```

But that caused

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid to many relationship in setPropertiesToFetch: (types.name)'
```

Comment: You want that a point is displayed in multiple sections if it has more than one type? That is not possible with a fetched results controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSFetchedResultsController` is very flexible and can be used with all kinds of views, not only table views.

The `sectionNameKeyPath` is of course wrong. It clearly has to be a to-one relationship. Assuming that one `MapPOI` can only have one type, the key path should be something like `@"type.name"`.

If, however one `MapPOI` can have several types, you could do the following:

Fetch the types entity rather than the POI entity. You do not need a section key path. Now `objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row` will fetch a `Type` managed object.

For number of sections use

```
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count
```

For section titles use

```
[[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:section] name];
```

For row count in section use

```
Type *type = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:section];
type.mapPOIs.count;
```

And it should be obvious how to populate the cell with the `MapPOI` entities.